# XPages: can I see somewhere on the XPage that validation has occured or not?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In my XPages application want to change the CSS of a alert box when validation has occured.

Can I somehow check if the XPage has a state of invalid to compute the class of the alert box?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered

`facesContext.getMessages().hasNext()` ?

https://www.intec.co.uk/how-many-xpages-errors-have-i-got/